# Is a database design's normal form the least of the normal forms of its tables?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I was wondering, if I have

```
Table1 -> 2NF
Table2 -> 3NF 
Table3 -> 3NF
```

then is my database design's normal form the least one among its tables' normal forms? In this case 2nf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When we say that a database is in a certain normal form we mean that every table in it is in at least that normal form.

Answer (score -2):

"Unfortunately, *'it depends'* ..."

"In the *real* world" ... *ahem...* *"'real(!)* life' is never so 'academically simple'."

Each table in a real-world(!) database must *pragmatically* be regarded as being "precisely what it *is,* for better or for worse." You cannot and must not assume ... *ahem* ... "that your present situation is ideal."

. . .

The pragmatic conformance of *any* real-world database table, to the purely-academic ideals of "normal form," very-much depend upon the exigencies that were perceived to have existed *at the time* that said tables were created, in response to the immediate business conditions of that time. (Which might well have been, "thirty years ago.")

Comment: Re: `the purely-academic ideals of "normal form,"` - data integrity is not a purely academic ideal, it's very much pragmatic.

Comment: Yes, but real databases *evolve* over time, as new software is introduced, as new capabilities are added to existing software, and as the business environment itself changes. The existing data structures do not change, since an unknown(!) amount of software depends upon them. Sometimes, the strictures imposed by a database are *too* strict for the actual business to allow. (As an example, check-numbers or invoice-numbers might actually be re-used, in the same or in different business offices, or in the historical records of a company that has been acquired. And, so on. *"Ka-ka ... occurs."*

Comment: Though check-numbers or invoice-numbers may be reused, the need remains to distinguish them. Adding a contextual attribute allows us to renormalize and maintain integrity. Highly normalized data survives change better since they represent simple elementary facts which are more likely to fall out of use than change structure. Changes in highly normalized models tend to be additions rather than modifications. Even the U in CRUD becomes less as simple facts need only be asserted or retracted.

Comment: *"Uhh, yeah, whatever ..."* Certainly, a lesson-learned in *pragmatic* database/data-store design is that "we must somehow dis-ambiguate 'inherently ambiguous things,'" at least for the immediate purposes of data storage. But, soon enough, *"the business* intervenes." The Sales department wants a Sales report, and it becomes *your(!)* unholy task to somehow produce one . . . "no matter what."

Comment: I'm not trying to be cute here.  The "normal-form-ness" of an entire *database* pragmatically depends on **much more** than "the lowest value of "n" for ***n*NF** among its possibly hundreds of tables. Databases *do* evolve over a period of years, and the exigencies of "supporting an actual *business"* (which is not always as "strict" in its meaning and interpretation of things as an SQL database would normally *[ahem...]* be, can render this question almost irrelevant.

Comment: Normal forms are absolutely about supporting the business - by ensuring the database accurately represents the desired business rules. How can satisfying a business rule be a "purely-academic" consideration? I don't think any of your comments are relevant to the question.

Comment: What I am saying, sqlvogel, is:  *(a)* that businesses constantly change, and are bought and sold. *(b)* Normal-forms are a *mathematical ideal* that do not always appear in practice. Some live, mission-critical databases are stored in SQL today, but pre-date SQL by many decades.  *(IDMS, I/VSAM ...)* If you work at a real business where every database you encounter is perfectly normalized and tidy, just like your college professors told you they "should" be, then count yourself ridiculously lucky. In 35 years I have *yet* to see it. Yes, you should *strive* to design things that way, "today."

Comment: Businesses change and databases change with them. It is stating the obvious to say that some databases are not normalized but it has no relevance to the question. You have made my point for me. Not all databases are normalized but many certainly are and should be. Normalization demonstrably has real, practical, business value and there's no justification for your answer that it is a "purely academic" ideal.

Comment: The business *risk* of making any change whatsoever to a legacy table that now supports a revenue-producing application (and, an unknown number of other important scripts that no one remembers(!)), is something that can never be dismissed. Both of our points-of-view are valid.

Comment: I certainly don't dismiss the business risk of making a change (or not making one). Your comment that normalization is "purely academic" seems very dismissive of business needs. I think that's an invalid and contradictory point-of-view given your other comments. Maybe you should consider changing the words of your answer.

Comment: Assume that I could have, indeed, chosen better words ... then. I guess that I used the word, "purely academic," partly because I have never yet seen a textbook that *(a)* discussed reasons why you might *not* choose an upper normal-form, and *(b)* discussed things that you might encounter in real databases and ways that you might need to "code around them." (Of course, students might not have enough experience yet, and of course, we don't want to scare them off!) **;-)** Thanks for this back-and-forth exchange, sqlvogel. Thank you very much.